# How to perform Django aggregate function over text

Tags: django, join, model, aggregate

I have a model that looks like the following:

```
class Loves(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Data in the model looks like:

poll    choice_text user

1   a   mike

1   b   mike

1   c   james

2   a   james

2   b   melody

1   d   mike

How do I output a list that looks like:

user    tuples
mike    (1,a),(1,b),(1,d)
james   (1,c), (2,a)
melody  (2,b)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection={} 
for l in Loves.objects.all():
    if l.user_name in collection:
        collection[l.user_name].append((l.poll,l.choice_text))
    else:
        collection[l.user_name]=[(l.poll,l.choice_text)]
# and to turn it into a list just do
results_list=list(collection)
```